# vscode text mate tokenizer broken?

Tags: visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting, tokenize, vs-color-theme-editor

My python interpreter(s) cannot seem to figured out what it is looking at I guess. I originally resolved this issue after uninstalling all my extensions and then reinstalling python extension pack, but it just happened again. I did not install any new extensions either, so I don't understand what is going on.

[image: color theme broken]

[image]

Comment: Find out the TextMate Class with the "Developer: Inspect ......" command

Comment: Which commands in VSC have the text `inspect` in the name, choose the one that is most appropriate

Comment: It is a lot easier if you edit your question. If the `textmate scopes` are different you get different colors